# Nested Resources - UrlGenerationError - No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-routes

I'm working on a basic Rails app. To get things going, I created two scaffolds.

- calendar
- content_items

I then created the proper associations.

**app/models/calendar.rb**

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :content_items
end
```

**app/models/content_item.rb**

```
class ContentItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :calendars do
  resources :content_items
end
```

However, now when I try to view the content_items of a specific calendar, I get the following error:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"show", :calendar_id=>nil, :controller=>"content_items", :id=>"5"} missing required keys: [:calendar_id]

It says the error is coming from:
**views/content_items/index.html.erb**

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', calendar_content_item_path(content_item.calendar, content_item) %></td>
```

I've tried a few different routes, but they lead to different errors. Do I need to update the model and/or controllers since I created the nested routes?

Comment: basically rails is unable to generate a url from only content_item object. as it is nested, you also need to pass parent calender object. check [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

`<td><%= link_to 'Show', calendar_content_item_path(content_item.calendar, content_item) %></td>`

Comment: Tried this. I think its closer. Updated code and error in original post.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check. There was a little spelling mistake :)

Comment: Updated original post again. Im confused by the error because it appears the ID is being passed in.

Comment: Is there any record where the is no calendar_id? Can you confirm if the association works?

Comment: Both models appear to be correct, but Im not sure of another way to check.

Comment: To check, just in the view,  for now comment the link and display content_item.calendar instead. If u get a object, it works fine

Comment: content_item.calendar doesn't throw an error, but it has a nill value.

Comment: so it means..there are some values..which does not have calendar_id, you can put validations and it should work

Comment: That was it. I needed to clear out the database of old data that didn't have a calendar_id. I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78733/discussion-between-amit-badheka-pykih-staff-and-jeremye).

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add `_path` suffix to route:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', content_items_path(calendar) %></td>
```

Comment: That leads to this: undefined local variable or method `content_item_path'

Comment: + forget to use plural form: `content_items_path`

Comment: + forget to pass `calendar` variable to identify related calendar